# Recover database until cancel without prompt?

Tags: oracle-11g-r2, recovery

The statement:

```
RECOVER DATABASE UNTIL CANCEL
```

prompts once to select the archive log file. Is there a way to pre specify the value so as to be able to use it in a script without prompt?

I have tried:

```
RECOVER AUTOMATIC DATABASE UNTIL CANCEL
```

But it still does prompt.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Issue a [SET AUTORECOVERY ON](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14357/ch12040.htm#i2698666) first.

Comment: I added a blank line in the script, which did the trick - as i only needed to press `ENTER` during prompt. I'll try your way also.